# GKE Stackdriver BadRequestException

Tags: php, google-kubernetes-engine, stackdriver

When I try to write the entry, I got an exception:

```
message:  "PHP Notice: Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\BadRequestException: {
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Log entry with size 5.00M exceeds maximum size of 256.0K",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
```

Is there a solution to write a large entry, or any other suggestions to collect logs on gke?

Comment: What's the point in writing a single, 5M large log entry?

Comment: @Nico Haase
It's a JSON response form an API.